# Why does $e^{(-x)^8}$ = $e^{x^8}$

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

can someone please explain to me why $e^{(-x)^8}$ = $e^{x^8}$ ?

Edit: OH CRAP I CAN'T TYPE... MY TITLE WAS WRONG. But my question is the same. When I typed out on desmos: $e^{(-x)^8}$, I get the same curve as $e^{(x)^8}$

Edit 2: OH MY GOD... I READ IT WRONG. IT'S $e^{(-x)^8}$

Comment: $e^{-x}$ is not (usually) $e^x$?

Comment: It is indeed, but haven't you misread $e^{(-x)}$ for $e^{|-x|}$?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  Where, for example, did you see someone claim the (obviously false) equality?

Comment: Sorry my equation was typed wrong, but my question still stands. I typed $e^{(-x)^8}$ and $e^{x^8}$ out on desmos and got the same slope

Comment: Because $(-x)^8=x^8$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does $e^{-x} = e^{x}?$

**It doesn't**, except for when $x = 0.$

---

Post-edit second question:

> Why does $e^{(-x)^8} = e^{x^8}$?

This is, in fact, true. When you raise a negative to an *even* power, you get a positive. You may already know that 
$$(-1)^2 = (-1)\cdot (-1) = 1.$$

More generally,
$$(-x)^{2n} = (-x)^n\cdot (-x)^n = (-1)\cdot(-1)\cdot x^n\cdot x^n =  x^{2n}.$$

Try instead $e^{(-x)^7}$, which won't equal $e^{x^7}$ because $7$ isn't even.

Comment: Oh I completely forgot about that! Sorry I haven't had my coffee yet :)